# Css !important formstyle.css to overlap a ul (with no class) from main.css

Tags: css

I have a website which includes a CSS file (main.css) that I am unable to change. I need to find a way to override all of the CSS styles in that file.

The main.css file (which must stay the same)

```
ul { padding-left: 25px; }
ul li { list-style-type: square; }
```

My custom css:

```
.personal ul { padding-left: 0px !important }
```

Is there a way to cancel out the entire scope of the main.css file?

Answer (score 0):

1. this css is for all ui

   ```
   ul { padding-left:25px;}
   ul li{ list-style-type: square; }
   ```
2. try to make the different setting with class or id

   ```
   ul  .personal{ padding-left:25px;}
   ul  .personal li{ list-style-type: square; }
   ```

so determine in html what you want, which it use standard setting, which it use custom setting .personal

```
    <ul > </ul> will use setting 1
    <ul class='personal'> </ul> will use setting 2
```